# Is there any Form Analytics tool that works behind a login?

Tags: marketing, data-analysis

I'm looking for a form analytics tool that works on a page after the user has logged in.
I came across some products that support heat map recording after login, but not form analytics.
Is there any tools available on the market?

Answer (score 0):

**All of the analytics tools I have used work on any page, regardless of being logged in or not.**

I've used Google Analytics, Adobe Experience Cloud, & Matomo, and they all are capable of recording events before and after login. These tools are all basically JavaScript functions that send IDs and data to specific URLs, so you can track any event on the form by just firing off a line of custom JS. Errors, focus on a field, time on page, etc. can all be tracked depending on what your goals are.

Even if your page is behind a firewall or not connected to the rest of the internet, you can still use tools like Matomo where you install them on your own server instead of needing to reach Google's servers.

If none of those are options, you can also obtain some data using server logs each time the form is submitted. This can be useful if you are mostly interested in error and success rates. You can even get a sense for how long people spend fixing errors by looking at the timestamps between events.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, I thought about Google Analytics but then found out that to enable form analytics (recording how long people spend for each form fields, where they drop etc) it would take time to customize GA & GTM. Meanwhile for specialized tools such as Hotjar or Mouseflow there would be minimum effort to create a beautiful & useful dashboard. I also talked to Mouseflow team and they confirmed that they support form analytics after login with some extra scripts.